# Affecting children of children of children using class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<tbody id="best_id_ever_1">
<tr>
<td>
<span class="to_affect">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

 <tbody id="best_id_ever_2">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <span class="to_affect">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>


 <tbody id="best_id_ever_3">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <span class="to_affect">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Using jquery, I'd like to affect the span being the grand-grand children of a tbody with a **given id**. I've tried the following:

```
$(best_id_ever_X).closest('.to_affect');
$(best_id_ever_X).children('.to_affect');
```

but yet, nothing. I could use some help here :p

Answer (score 2):

here is how you get the object you want:

```
$("#best_id_ever_1").find(".to_affect");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example HTML, you don't really need to worry how many levels of descendants you have. The `<span>` that you're looking to target already has a class name that you can use to target it.

Using the `id` attribute, you retrieve the "root" element -

```
var root_elem = $( "#best_id_eva" );
```

Now, using the [jquery `find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function, you can target just the `<span>` you wish to manipulate:

```
var affected_span = root_elem.find( "span.to_affect" );
```

---

As an additional example, I'll take your example HTML literally and traverse the DOM directly to the `<span>`:

```
var affected_span = $( "#best_id_eva > tr > td > span");
```

This will match

- *all* `<span>` elements
- that are direct descendants of a `<td>`
- who in turn are direct descendants of a `<tr>`
- that are contained within an element with an `id` of `best_id_eva`.